# Grepping the multiple words from file

Tags: file, bash, shell, grep

I have one file (approx 1000 words).

1.txt:

```
XYZ

ABC

DEF

GHI

...
```

And I have another file *2.txt* which contains some data, now I want to grep these words in *1.txt*  in the file *2.txt*.
I have used the below logic, but an error is given.

```
name=$(cat 1.txt |tr '\n' '|')

grep -E -w ${name} 2.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Grep can read patterns from a file using the `-f` option:

```
egrep -w -f 1.txt 2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you need quotes and use egrep

```
egrep -w "$(cat 1.txt |tr '\n'  '|')" 2.txt
```

but the answer with -f is better

Comment: `egrep` is another way to invoke `grep -E`, which he is already doing. Quoting may or may not be necessary, depending on the content of 1.txt, but of course is a good idea.